# How to convert a dataframe to vector which will be used as a parameter in a function that only accept ONE parameter in R

Tags: r

I want to convert XYZ to Lab color space using `XYZ2Lab` function in `colorscience` package, however the function only accept one parameter (a vector including three number joined with `c`), and I want to convert a series of XYZs which was stored in a dataframe. Which function should I use to convert the dataframe to a vector that can be used by `XYZ2Lab` without using loop?

```
xyzs <-structure(list(X = c(33.75, 30.56, 31.1, 26.3, 36.27, 33.44, 
31.85, 32.83, 33.49, 31.14), Y = c(34.94, 31.67, 31.93, 27.55, 
36.46, 33.64, 32.62, 34.41, 34.35, 31.67), Z = c(7.59, 7.26, 
8.39, 8.5, 8.77, 8.18, 8.87, 14.78, 9.8, 8.76)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 10L))
colorscience::XYZ2Lab(xs) #could not be run.
#Error in XYZmatrix[, 1]/Rx : non-numeric argument to binary operator
xs <- some function (xyzs)??

colorscience::XYZ2Lab(xs)
```

Comment: `XYZ2Lab` wants a matrix and you have a `data.frame`. Just try `XYZ2Lab(as.matrix(xyzs))`.

Comment: @nicola perfect. thanks

Answer (score 1):

without a converting and loop,

```
t(apply(xyzs,1,XYZ2Lab))
```

could be used